# Using SQL aggregate functions outside of a group

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate

I have a table, call it TEST, like this one:

```
+----+--------+
| id | PRCNTG |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 10     | 
|  2 | 20     | 
|  2 | 30     | 
|  3 | 40     | 
|  4 | 50     | 
|  5 | 20     | 
|  5 | 10     | 
|  6 | 20     | 
+----+--------+
```

The `PRCNTG` column, in this instance, totals 200. It won't always.

If I perform this query:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(PRCNTG) FROM TEST GROUP BY ID;
```

I expect to get the following results:

```
+----+--------+
| id | PRCNTG |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 10     | 
|  2 | 50     | 
|  3 | 40     | 
|  4 | 50     | 
|  5 | 30     | 
|  6 | 20     | 
+----+--------+
```

However, I actually want to get the percentage of the `PRCNTG` column from the total. In other words, I would like to do something like this.

```
SELECT ID, 100 * (SUM(PRCNTG)/TOTAL(PRCNTG)) FROM TEST GROUP BY ID;
```

Where `TOTAL()` is some theoretical function that ignores grouping. So in this case it should always return 200. In theory, this would result in output like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | PRCNTG |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  5     | 
|  2 | 25     | 
|  3 | 20     | 
|  4 | 25     | 
|  5 | 15     | 
|  6 | 10     | 
+----+--------+
```

Basically, what I am asking, is if there is a way to use an aggregate function and tell it to ignore the grouping?

The simple workaround is to run the same query without grouping, just to get the `SUM()` into a variable, and then use that variable in place of the `TOTAL(PRCNTG)`, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
SELECT @TOTAL = SUM(PRCNTG) FROM TEST;
SELECT ID, 100 * (SUM(PRCNTG)/@TOTAL) FROM TEST GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a window function.  Try this:

```
SELECT ID, 100 * (SUM(PRCNTG)/sum(sum(PRCNTG)) over ())
FROM TEST
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you are storing `PRCNTG` as an integer then you will want to convert this to a fixed or floating point format of some sort:

```
SELECT ID, 100 * (SUM(cast(PRCNTG as float))/sum(sum(PRCNTG)) over ())
FROM TEST
GROUP BY ID;
```